# Python string formatting when iterating through lists

Tags: python

I have a simple program that takes a sentence and calculates the number of lowercase, uppercase, digits and punctuation characters. I need to output into a format like this:

```
# Upper   # Lower   # Digits  # Punct.
--------  --------  --------  --------
   2         36        4         5
```

However, in my code, I have combined the headers, bars and the counts into a separate list. Here is my code:

```
#Prompting user to enter a sentence
input_string = input("Please enter a sentence: ")

#Initializing variables
lowercase_count = 0
uppercase_count = 0
punctuation_count = 0
digits_count = 0

#Iterating through the string to get the counts
for str in input_string:
    if str.isupper():
        uppercase_count +=1
    elif str.islower():
        lowercase_count +=1
    elif str in (".", "?", '!', ",", ";", ":", "-", "\'" ,"\""):
        punctuation_count +=1
    elif str.isnumeric():
        digits_count +=1

header_list = ["# Upper", "# Lower", "# Digits", "# Punct."]
bars_list = ['----------']*4
counts_list = [uppercase_count
               , lowercase_count
               , digits_count
               , punctuation_count]

comb_list = [header_list, bars_list, counts_list]

for list in comb_list:
    print("{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}".format(list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3]))
```

Which gives me an output like this:

```
# Upper        # Lower        # Digits       # Punct.       
----------     ----------     ----------     ----------     
              1             16              0              1
```

If I were to print out the header, list and counts separately, I can control the align parameter

```
#Printing Header
print("{:15}{:15}{:15}{:15}"
      .format(header_list[0], header_list[1], header_list[2], header_list[3]))

#Printing bars
for header in header_list:
    print("{:15}".format("----------"), end="")

#Printing values
print("\n{:5}{:15}{:15}{:15}"
      .format(uppercase_count
              , lowercase_count
              , digits_count
              , punctuation_count))
```

which gives me the expected output:

```
# Upper        # Lower        # Digits       # Punct.       
----------     ----------     ----------     ----------     
    1             16              0              1
```

How do I control the align parameter when iterating through list of lists? What's the best way to print the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Response:**

I looked at your code and the way your header is formatted, there is some alignment to be done. So try this and it will center itself. For every column, I am subtracting 5 and adding it to the next column. The reason: you have a space of 5 chars between each column. So I have to adjust for that.

```
print("\n{:^10}{:^20}{:^10}{:^20}"
```

The alternate to do this is:

```
print("\n{:^10}     {:^10}     {:^10}     {:^10}"
```

The output for this are as follows:

```
# Upper        # Lower        # Digits       # Punct.       
----------     ----------     ----------     ----------     
    1              16             0              1          

    32             16             7              12
```

**Earlier response:**

Can you try to give the following to center it:

```
print("\n{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}{:^15}"
```

To format the data, use one of these options. By default, strings are left justified and numbers are right justified.

```
< is for left justified
> is for right justified
^ is for center justified
```

You can learn more about [formatting](https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/string/python-data-type-string-exercise-37.php) here

Comment: I tried this formatting but didn't give me the expected results

Comment: I made some updates based on your code. See the results now.

Comment: why are we adding a space inside the print?

Comment: Your text is setup that way so we need to either provide space or use 10,20,10,20 option